# Silverstripe: Disable CSRF for particular IP

Tags: silverstripe

I want to disable `CSRF` security token on my Silverstripe for particular IP.

I know for particular form it can be done via

```
$form = new Form(..);
$form->disableSecurityToken();
```

But I want to do it site wise.

I have another site hosted on another computer, which makes an ajax call for a silverstripe login using `XSLT` and `ajax`. So I want to disable CSRF sitewise for this particular IP.

Can anyone help me on this??
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) for the remote IP:

```
$ip = '192.168.1.99'; 

if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $ip) {
    $form->disableSecurityToken();
}
```

This could work if the ajax call is made by the other **server**, if it's made by the browser the IP is always different.

EDIT:

if you want to disable the security token globally you can either use

```
SecurityToken::disable();
```

or plug an `Extension` class to `Controller` with the magic method `securityTokenEnabled()`which returns false. Of course a special controller subclass could overwrite this. See [source](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/source-class-Form.html#262-270).

Comment: can I use it in `mysite/_config.php`, I want to disable it site wise for all forms not just one form.

Comment: `SecurityToken::disable();` sounds like it will work.  http://api.silverstripe.org/3.0/class-SecurityToken.html#_disable

Comment: be carefully... I doubt it's a good idea to disable it globally.